# TypeError: _co.changeLanguage is not a function (Ionic 3, Angular 4, ngx-translate)

Tags: angular, ionic3, typeerror, ngx-translate

I have a translation service according to this tutorial http://codingscripts.com/ionic-3-multi-language-app/ and it works fine. But in this tutorial you add the buttons to change the language on the **home.html** page.

I want my buttons to be in the side menu of my app, so this would be the app.html.
I added the buttons to my **app.html** like:

```
<button (click)="changeLanguage('de')">
        Translate to German
</button>
<button (click)="changeLanguage('fr')">
        Translate to French
</button>
```

My **app.component.ts** looks like this:

```
import ......
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  ...;

  constructor(..., public translate: TranslateService) {
    ....
    });
  }

  changeLanguage(language) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }    
}
```

When I start my app and I click on the button, I get this error: **TypeError: _co.changeLanguage is not a function**

I've already googled this error but couldn't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: can you share the entire errorStack? and your app.component.ts?

Comment: Just stop the **ionic serve** and rerun it again. In Ionic If you added any addition function that will not reflect in live-reload.

Comment: @yousuf That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your function is outside of your class scope, this is what it appears when I tried your code.

you have to move it inside your "MyApp" class. and try to define a class with the name "AppPage" and put your function inside it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I'm sure your solution also works but I solved it just through rerunning the ionic serve command.